# never keyword used in type parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
export const getArraySemigroup = <A = never>(): Semigroup<Array<A>> => {
  return {
    concat: (x, y) => concat(x, y)
  }
}
```

My understanding of `never` is that it is something that will never be resolved, is it being used as a default paramter her?

I've never (pun intended) seen a type parameter with an equals sign before.

Comment: you can check out the thread on default generic types here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2175 . Why the `never` type is used here I don't know though, you've gotta ask the one that wrote it what it means..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<A = never>` is [generic type default value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults). By default, generic type default value is empty object, `<{}>`.

As stated in [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never),

> The never type represents the type of values that never occur. For instance, never is the return type for a function expression or an arrow function expression that always throws an exception or one that never returns; Variables also acquire the type never when narrowed by any type guards that can never be true.

This piece of code basically forces a developer to always use generic function with explicit type argument.